# How to get notified when a google doc changes

Tags: python, google-api, google-docs

I want to create a python script which processes a google doc and then takes action based upon its contents.

In the api I can see how to download the document, which should prove useful, but how do I get notified when the document contents change?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*There is no API endpoint **nor** Apps Script trigger that you can use to get the information that the content of a Google Doc has changed.*

#### More Information:

There is no API endpoint which sets up notifications of any sort when a Document changes. An `onEdit()` trigger does not even exist in Apps Script for Google Docs - I presume this is because edits are constantly saved and so with an `onEdit()` trigger API requests would be constantly firing.

#### A Different Solution:

My suggestion for the time being would be to set up a cron (or other similar time-based job scheduler) job to make API requests at a regular frequency (say, once per 10 seconds or so to keep within the [Docs API Usage limits](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits)) which makes a read request to the document and compares its hash to a locally-stored hash. If these are the same you can be safe in assuming that no edit to the document has been made, and that there has if the hashes are different.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Simple Triggers - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- [Google Apps Script - Available types of triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers)
- [Google Gocs > API v1 - Usage limits](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits)
- [Wikipedia - cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)
- [Wikipedia - Hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)